# Pushing Elements to same array in multiple loops

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array named $fields, and I keep pushing elements to it in multiple level of loops.
The pattern of items being pushed is quite similar and the code is getting repeated.
Is there a better way to implement in PHP or Laravel.

My result should be something like
My code looks like

```
 foreach ($systems as $system) {
        $order++;
        $systemLevel++;
        $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeInt, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_map_order . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $systemLevel];
        $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeStr, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_map_name . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $system->map_name];
        $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeMap, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_map_id . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $system->map_id];
        $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeInt, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_parent_map_id . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $parentOrder];

        $siteParentOrder = $order;
        foreach ($local_sites as $local_site) {
            $local_site_acronym = $local_site->acronym;
            $sites = CmsSiteStructure::getChildElement($system->map_id, $local_site_acronym); //Eg : MS-ML, SS-ML
            foreach ($sites as $site) {
                $order++;
                $siteLevel++;
                $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeInt, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_map_order . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $siteLevel];
                $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeStr, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_map_name . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $site->map_name];
                $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeMap, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_map_id . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $site->map_id];
                $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeInt, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_parent_map_id . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $siteParentOrder];

                $segments = CmsSiteStructure::getChildElement($site->map_id, $local_site_acronym); //Eg : MS-ML-ENR-APP
                $siteParentOrder = $order;
                foreach ($segments as $segment) {
                    $order++;
                    $segmentLevel++;
                    $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeInt, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_map_order . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $segmentLevel];
                    $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeStr, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_map_name . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $segment->map_name];
                    $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeMap, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_map_id . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $segment->map_id];
                    $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeInt, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_parent_map_id . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $siteParentOrder];

                    $subsystems = CmsSiteStructure::getChildElement($segment->map_id, $local_site_acronym); //Eg : MS-ML-ENR-APP-ATM
                    $siteParentOrder = $order;
                    foreach ($subsystems as $subsystem) {
                        $order++;
                        $subsystemLevel++;
                        $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeInt, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_map_order . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $subsystemLevel];
                        $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeStr, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_map_name . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $subsystem->map_name];
                        $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeMap, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_map_id . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $subsystem->map_id];
                        $fields[] = [self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_TYPE => $typeInt, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_NAME => $lbl_parent_map_id . $order, self::LBL_ZABBIX_MAP_VALUE => $siteParentOrder];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

As you can see the $fields[] is repeated at every inner levels.

Can I make it in a nice shorter, better way.

Comment: whats is $arr1, $arr2 and $arr3. What is the content? $id, $name, $parent, $map? if you want to merge multiple array, you can use array_merge

Comment: can you show us what you have, and what you want the result?

Comment: looking at your given example, it feels like parent loops and child loops are not related at all. If you do not provide a basic data set we will not be able to know why $arr1 is used for parent loop and why $arr2 is for the child.